# Understanding Pandas Series Data Structure

Tags: pandas

I am trying to get my head around the Pandas module and started learning about the Series data structure.

I have created the following Series in Spyder :-

```
songs = pd.Series(data = [145,142,38,13], name = "Count")
```

I can obtain information about the Series index using the code:-

```
songs.index
```

The output of the above code is as follows:-

[image]

My question is where it states Start = 0 and Stop = 4, what are these referring to?
I have interpreted start = 0 as the first element in the Series is in row 0.
But i am not sure what Stop value refers to as there are no elements in row 4 of the Series?
Can some one explain?

Thank you.

Comment: It is basically the same as `range(start=0, stop=4, step=1)` the value in `stop` argument is not included, that's why you see `0, 1, 2, 3`.

Comment: [RangeIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.RangeIndex.html) is upperbound non-inclusive this is exactly the same behaviour as python's [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range).

Answer (score 0):

This concept as already **explained adequately** in the comments **(indexing is at minus one the count of items)** is **prevalent** in many places.

For instance, take the **list data structure-**

```
z = songs.to_list()
[145, 142, 38, 13]

len(z)
4 # length is four

# however indexing stops at i-1 position 'i' being the length/count of items in the list.   
z[4] # this will raise an IndexError

# you will have to start at index 0 going till only index 3 (i.e. 4 items)
z[0], z[1], z[2], z[-1] # notice how -1 can be used to directly access the last element
```